# what does "*&" mean together?

Tags: c++, pointers

For example:

```
private:
    Node* curr;
public:
    Node*& Iterator::getCurr() {
        return curr;
    }

    bool Iterator::operator==(const Iterator& other) {
        return curr == other.getCurr();
    }
```

I'm getting error in this code:

> passing ‘const Iterator’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Node*&
>   Iterator::getCurr()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

How should I fix it?

Comment: You're returning a reference to a pointer. It's hard to tell from your question whether that's what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry that I changed my question a lot. But, I think it's clearer now

Comment: You will fix it by first providing a description of the error you encounter. Otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: ok, I have just provided above

Comment: Can you, please, help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node*&` means “reference to pointer to `Node`”. You can return it as normal. Accessing it, however, can be done two ways: the ‘normal’ way, where the “reference to” part will just be dropped, and the way preserving the reference. The advantage of the latter way is you can change the underlying `curr` value:

```
Node *&curr = iterator.getCurr();
curr = new Node();  // or something like that
// iterator.curr has been changed
```

Answer (score 2):

don't read them together

if you see something like this:

```
Foo& foo();
```

Do you know what does the `&` means?

It is a reference to Foo

Then

```
Foo* foo();
```

What about this? this is Pointer to Foo

Then

```
Foo*& foo();
```

is reference to "Pointer to Foo"

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to a pointer to `Node`.